# How to remove style=xx from url with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, web-crawler

Could someone help me with a long time problem? Google is crawling a old style and it's messing up my page indexing.

The url is: `http://www.mywebsite.com/forum/viewtopic.php?STYLE=54&f=182&t=3587`

What I want to do is to remove "`style=54`".. is this possible? if so could someone help me with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to your htaccess file in your document root, above any rules you may already have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^STYLE=[0-9]+&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect the browser to the same URI but with the `STYLE=###` part removed from the query string. So in your example, the browser would then load:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=182&t=3587
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response @Jon Lin ! your code removed style=54 but it also removed /forum/. I tested with a clean htaccess. Do you know what may causing it?

Comment: @GöstaHonk update your question with your .htaccess and all the rules you have. Jon's answer does exactly what you asked so I believe you either have your browser cached with previous redirects or you have other rules that may be affecting it.

Comment: It worked after I removed the WWW rewrite in my Forum htaccess file. Thankyou. Any chance to get both codes to work togheter? (edits in my first post)

Comment: @GöstaHonk I don't see why they wouldn't work together as the STYLE rule doesn't mess with the hostname, scheme, or URI. Try switching the order.